# Safari 9 paints only the first frame of a video on canvas (bug)

Tags: javascript, canvas, safari, html5-video, osx-elcapitan

I'm trying to paint **the current frame** of a `<video>` on a canvas but **Safari 9.0.3 on 10.11 only paints the first frame**… sometimes! It appears to work only after the video is cached because a hard refresh causes it to not work again.

`.drawImage(video, 0, 0, width, height)` is how I'm painting it.

---

This simple snippet works correctly in all browsers, including Safari 9 Yosemite, but not in Safari 9 El Capitan

```js
var video = document.querySelector('video');
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
canvas.addEventListener('click', function () {
  canvas
  .getContext('2d')
  .drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
});
```

```html
<p>Play the video and then click on the canvas to paint</p>
<canvas width='240' height='135' style="border: solid;"></canvas>
<video width='240' height='135' controls loop src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4"></video>
```

Is there any workaround? Any other way to paint videos on canvas?

Comment: can't repro safari 9.0.3 on mavericks. Ps : I don't know any other *front-end* way to paint a video on a canvas than through drawImage()

Comment: By my testing it only happens on El Capitan. bfred, are you using El Capitan as well?

Comment: Correct, I'm on El Capitan, I updated the answer

Comment: I'm experiencing the same thing.  Works a treat in FF/Chrome, but no Safari love.  I've tried introducing a delay after starting the clip, but that doesn't fix anything.  Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: Other than manually decoding the video in javascript (very expensive), no, still broken and [not recognized as a bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=153588)

Comment: If you want it fixed, get a Bugzilla account and run the test case attached to the https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=153588 and leave a comment with your config and whether it works or not.

Comment: I opened that bug and created the test case, I think I already left a comment with my config (Safari 9/10.12). Is that what you meant?

Comment: I was meaning for anyone else to add their voice in the comments of the bug you created.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean, that'd help.

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue.  It appears that switching to a different desktop and coming back to the one with Safari will let drawImage grab the correct frame. I'm wondering if there is a way to programmatically in javascript to force a similar refresh?

Comment: I just tested the Safari Technology Preview and I am still seeing the same issue.

Comment: 2017 update - I notice this is still an issue.  I'm able to reproduce on macOS Sierra Safari 10 and Safari Tech Preview.  The issue occurs about 50% of the time and is extremely frustrating with no decent workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Using blob cache seems to work even on Safari

Sample (in CoffeeScript):

```
prepareLocalCache: ->
    @vidtemp = document.createElement('video')
    @vidtemp.preload = 'auto'
    @xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest
    @xhr.open 'GET', 'video link here.mp4', true
    @xhr.responseType = 'blob'
    @xhr.onload = (e) =>
      if e.currentTarget.status == 200
        myBlob = e.currentTarget.response
        @vidcache = window.URL.createObjectURL(myBlob)
        @vidtemp.src = @vidcache
    @xhr.send()

...
...

context = canvas.getContext '2d'
context.drawImage @vidtemp, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height
```

@vidtemp is a dynamically created video tag.